# What is a vague prior for λ in Gamma(n,λ), where n is a constant not equaling 1?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem, gamma-distribution

I know that for λ in Poi(λ) or Exp(λ) a vague prior for λ is π(λ) ∼ Gamma (α, β) where α and β are small, I was wondering if it was the same for λ in Gamma(n,λ) since exponential distribution is a special case of gamma distribution.

Comment: Yes, if $n$ is known. A single observation $x$ will then give a posterior distribution for the rate of $\text{Gamma}(\alpha+n, \beta+x)$

Comment: Is it more suitable if I use Gamma(1,0.01) to simulate the vague prior, or is there a specific preference for the use of α? Does α=1,a>1,a<1 have different impact on the vagueness of my prior?